# Setting default value of filtered object in HapiJS Confidence configuration object

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, hapi.js, winston

I'm using the [Confidence](https://github.com/hapijs/confidence) library (in the HapiJS suite) for configuration management in my project (This config file specifically is for WinstonJS transports), and I was wondering if it was possible to set a default value for a single item in a filtered object. I'm not sure I'm explaining this right, I'm not positive what the correct terminology is, so heres an example:

I have a section of my configuration setup like so currently:

```js
module.exports =  {
    $filter: 'env',
    development: {
        level: {
            console: 'debug',
            file: 'debug'
        },
        path: 'app-core.log'
    },
    staging: {
        level: {
            console: 'warn',
            file: 'warn'
        },
        path: 'app-core.log'
    },
    production: {
        level: {
            console: 'error',
            file: 'error'
        },
        path: 'prod-app-core.log'
    }
}
```

But since the `path` should be the same for all of the `env` items, with the exception of `production`, I was hoping that I could set the default value for just the `path` value. Something like this:

```js
module.exports =  {
    $filter: 'env',
    development: {
        level: {
            console: 'debug',
            file: 'debug'
        }
    },
    staging: {
        level: {
            console: 'warn',
            file: 'warn'
        }
    },
    production: {
        level: {
            console: 'error',
            file: 'error'
        },
        path: 'prod-app-core.log'
    },
    $default: {
        path: 'app-core.log'
    }
}
```

Obviously, that doesn't work, but I hope it illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish. I can't find a way to set default values for single config items within objects, if I apply a filter (say `staging`), then it takes the entire staging object, and doesn't even look at the `$default` object.

Thanks!

**P.S.** While I would like to know if this is possible via Confidence (for other purposes), if it turns out that this isn't possible, then is there a way to set the default path for WinstonJS file transports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `$base`. See the [shared values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/confidence#shared-values) section in the docs:

> If you have values that you would like to share between various configuration objects without duplicating them for each option, you can create a `$base` object.

Here's how it's used with your example:

```
const Confidence = require('confidence');

const document = {
    $filter: 'env',
    $base: {
        path: 'app-core.log'
    },
    development: {
        level: {
            console: 'debug',
            file: 'debug'
        }
    },
    staging: {
        level: {
            console: 'warn',
            file: 'warn'
        }
    },
    production: {
        level: {
            console: 'error',
            file: 'error'
        },
        path: 'prod-app-core.log'
    }
};

const store = new Confidence.Store(document);

console.log(store.get('/', { env: 'production' }));
console.log(store.get('/', { env: 'development' }));
```

Console output:

```
{ path: 'prod-app-core.log',
  level: { console: 'error', file: 'error' } }
{ path: 'app-core.log',
  level: { console: 'debug', file: 'debug' } }
```

**So what's `$default` for then?**

`$default` is used to define an object that should be used when the env value doesn't have a corresponding key in the document. Without a `$default`, you'd just get `undefined` for that path:

```
const document = {
    $filter: 'env',
    $base: {
        path: 'app-core.log'
    },
    $default: {
        level: {
            console: 'something-else',
            file: 'something-else'
        }
    },
    development: {
        level: {
            console: 'debug',
            file: 'debug'
        }
    },
    staging: {
        level: {
            console: 'warn',
            file: 'warn'
        }
    },
    production: {
        level: {
            console: 'error',
            file: 'error'
        },
        path: 'prod-app-core.log'
    }
};

const store = new Confidence.Store(document);

console.log(store.get('/', { env: 'dunno' }));
```

Console output:

```
{ path: 'app-core.log',
  level: { console: 'something-else', file: 'something-else' } }
```

Anything defined at `$default` level or a specific matching filter value will take precedence over the value defined at `$base`.

Comment: Yep! Ironically, I found the `$base` in my own JS files, it was just a while ago, I didnt remember I used it. But thats it! Thanks